# Save modal body as image / PDF when clicking the download button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm just wondering if the modal body can be saved as an image or a PDF. The data on my modal is illustrated in the image below. I generated the data using PHP and MySQL, and as you can see, the only image is the QR image. When I click the download button, I want to save the entire modal body as an image / pdf file. Is it possible?

[image]

Here's the code that I'm currently using with the modal.

```
<div class="modal-body" >
  <div id="cts-card" style="overflow: auto;" align="center">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <br>
        <div class="card-body" id="mod-body">
          <div id="userInfo" style="display: none;"></div>
          <?php
            $userData = array();
            if(!empty($row['u_id'])){
                // Include the database configuration file
                $db = OpenCon();
            
                // Get the user's ID from the URL
                $userID = $row['u_id'];
                // Fetch the user data based on the ID
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = ".$userID);
            
                if($query->num_rows > 0){
                    $userData = $query->fetch_assoc();
                }
            }
            ?>
          <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" style="width: 3.5in;border-collapse: collapse;" id="myTable">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding-top:5%;">
                <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="../assets/images/logo/logo.png" alt="SMS Logo" style="width: 70%;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php if(!empty($userData)){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="../temp/<?php echo $userData['qr']; ?>.png" alt="Contact Tracing Card" width="80%">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:5%;">
                <p class="card-title">
                  <b>
                  <?php echo strtoupper($userData['fname']." ".$userData['mname']." ".$userData['lname']." ".$userData['suffix']); ?>
                  </b>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <?php
                    if ($userData['dept'] == "GS") {
                      echo strtoupper("Grade School");
                    } else if ($userData['dept'] == "JHS") {
                      echo strtoupper("Junior High School");
                    } else if ($userData['dept'] == "SHS") {
                      echo strtoupper("Senior High School");
                    }
                    echo ' | ';
                    if ($userData['user_type'] == "S") {
                      echo strtoupper("Student");
                    } else if ($userData['user_type'] == "E") {
                      echo strtoupper("Employee");
                    } else if ($userData['user_type'] == "P") {
                      echo strtoupper("Parent");
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }else{ ?>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <p>User not found...</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary"
    data-bs-dismiss="modal">
  <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
  <span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="printDiv();">
  <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
  <span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="convert">
  <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
  <span class="d-none d-sm-block"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</span>
  </button>
  <script>
    function printDiv() {
        var divContents = document.getElementById("mod-body").innerHTML;
        var a = window.open('', '', 'height=900, width=800');
        a.document.write('<html>');
        a.document.write('<head><title>ISKULTrace</title></head><link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">');
        a.document.write('<body >');
        a.document.write(divContents);
        a.document.write('</body></html>');
        a.document.close();
        a.print();
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: @KJ I tried researching on how can I save it but I can't find anything that's why I asked here. Anyway, it is on the admin side since we will just use it locally. So after saving it as image, we will just give it to the users. You mentioned JS so I'll try searching with it. Thank you!

Comment: @KJ sorry. It only save the QR image if I use the right click function so the text are not included. I need to save it with the text.

Comment: @KJ sorry about that. I'll update it with a code.

Comment: @KJ I tried using the html2canvas but I think it is not working if I'm using modal.